# Symfony 3 and Sonata Admin file upload

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I believe that I have tried a lot of tutorials and now I'm out of ideas. I would like to create File entity which will hold details of each file uploaded to the system and it will use OneToOne relationship to other entities. I have used that approach on Symfony 2.4 and it was fine but with Symfony 3 I get unexpected errors. I use Sonata Admin for backend data management. One of the problems is that I'm getting array instead of the File object on file setter setFile

So I have Post entity

```
class Post extends BasePageModel
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="File", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="file_id", onDelete="CASCADE", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $file;

    ...

    /**
     * Set file
     *
     * @param File $file
     *
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setFile(File $file = null)
    {
       $this->file = $file;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get file
     *
     * @return File
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    ...

}
```

and I'm receiving an error: `Expected value of type "File" for association field "Post#$file", got "array" instead.`

Comment: Can you provide form class for this entity?

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the form type class I have noticed that I didn't setDefaults with data_class via the configureOptions:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
      'data_class' => BaseFile::class
    ));
}
```

After that the data underlying this file has become a File object not an array.